# Reducing the Parceljs bundler build size with Antd library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, parceljs

I am using ParcelV2 to create bundles for my typescript React application.
Below are my details,

```
/// package.json

"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "REACT_APP_MODE=dev parcel public/index.html --open --port 3000",
    "start": "rimraf .parcel-cache && parcel public/index.html --open --port 3000",
    "build:widget": "rimraf widget .parcel-cache && parcel build src/index.tsx --dist-dir widget",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "format": "prettier \"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,scss,html,md,json,test.jsx,test.tsx,test.js,test.ts}\" --write",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "antd": "^4.20.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "constate": "^3.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.26.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.1",
    "i18next": "^21.6.14",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "rc-select": "^14.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@parcel/compressor-brotli": "2.4.0",
    "@parcel/compressor-gzip": "2.4.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-inline-string": "2.4.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-svg-react": "^2.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.10",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^25.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
    "parcel": "^2.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "yarn run test"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,scss,html,md,json,test.jsx,test.tsx,test.js,test.ts}": "yarn run format",
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "yarn run lint:fix"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "eslint-plugin-import/tsconfig-paths/minimist": "^1.2.6"
  }
```

And below is my parcel configurations,

```
/// .parcelrc
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.svg": [
      "...",
      "@parcel/transformer-svg-react"
    ]
  },
  "compressors": {
    "*.{html,css,js,svg,map}": [
      "...",
      "@parcel/compressor-gzip",
      "@parcel/compressor-brotli"
    ]
  }
}
```

**ISSUE:**

If I run the production build for files when `Antd` Library is used, the build size is more than expected, [Check the FinanceOverview.920671fd.js file]

[image]

But if I removed Antd library, then build size will be dropped drastically. See the below screenshot,

[image]

**STEPS TAKEN:**

I tried to use React Lazy import to create a separate chunks and it helps to reduce the size from MB to kb but still it is greater than `500Kb`.

I checked the Parcel docs where they mentioned tree shaking, multiple small chunks, etc will be done automatically during the production build. But it's not happening right now.

**EXPECTED:**
Multiple chunk files with minimal size

Below is the the screenshot from Bundle Buddy Report,
[image]

I didn't see any issue with Antd library in this report.

I am not sure why the bundle size is drastically changing with/without `Antd` Library. So kindly anyone help me how we can optimize this production build and reduce the file?

Comment: What do you see when you run `parcel build src/index.tsx --log-level verbose`? According to [the docs](https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/#avoiding-bail-outs) this should print out diagnostics about when scope-hoisting "bails-out". The same docs have a lot of tips on how to maximize the effectiveness of scope-hoisting and reduce bundle size.

Comment: I tried this now and getting `@parcel/transformer-js: Non-static access of an import or require. This causes tree shaking to be disabled for the resolved module.` warnings everywhere. Even it is showing the warning for the places where I imported React.

Comment: Hmm... this might be hard to debug without a concrete repro because of [this issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7109). Can you provide one, maybe on github? Basically, that error is fired on all sorts of actually-fine code (that doesn't stop tree-shaking). And it seems like some of your issue is that antd code is somehow duplicated in each bundle instead of being split into it's own chunk and only referenced once. It could be a bug in parcel, or there might be an easy fix...hard to say without seeing it.